# "A specified Include path is not valid” when using Include

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, entity

When I use the `Include` method I got this error:

> A specified Include path is not valid

My classes:

```
public class ClubMember
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

public class Card
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int CardNumber { get; set; }

    public ClubMember Member { get; set; }
}
```

The string when i got error:

```
IList<Card> cards = db.Cards.Include(n => n.Member.Name).Include(n => n.Member.Date).ToList();
```

I want get this combined table:

> CardNumber | Name | Date

What is wrong?

Comment: `.Include(n => n.Member)` should be enough.

Comment: I try this, but i got worse result: | CardNumber | Member | In member field only this strings: "MyDataBase.Data.Entities.ClubMember"

Comment: @viton-zizu No, the property `Member` doesn't return the string `"MyDataBase.Data.Entities.ClubMember"`, it returns an object of type `MyDataBase.Data.Entities.ClubMember`, for which the `ToString()` function (that you shouldn't be calling) returns `"MyDataBase.Data.Entities.ClubMember"`. Instead of calling that `ToString()` function, refer to the object's properties `Name` and `Date`.

Comment: @viton-zizu: I included a short snippet in my answer how to access them, but maybe you should read up on "how EF works" a little more. EF is an ORM and does not return "tables", but "entites" including "navigation properties" for related entities...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Include` is to include entites not properties:

```
var cards = db.Cards.Include(n => n.Member).ToList();
```

This will eager-load the related `Member`-entity for every `Card` loaded (including all scalar properties).
Then you can access them:

```
foreach (var card in cards)
{
    int cardNumber = card.CardNumber;
    string name = card.Member.Name;
    DateTime date = card.Member.Date;
}
```

If you only want to get that three properties you could also map a query to an anonymous type:

```
var cards = db.Cards.Select(c => 
                new {
                    CardNumber = c.CardNumber,
                    Name = c.Member.Name,
                    Date = c.Member.Date
                }
            ).ToList();

foreach (var card in cards)
{
    int cardNumber = card.CardNumber;
    string name = card.Name;
    DateTime date = card.Date;
}
```

But this only makes sense if you table is actually much bigger than shown here. If they are not I would definitely go with the "real entites" - especially if you want to update them at some point.

Comment: Excuse me, everything worked out! Big thank you again!